# Magento Magmi (Configurable product) unable to import type column

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, magmi

Hi I have been stuck on this for hours.

Magmi unable to import my products with the column "type". It throws an error on my configurable row with this:

> SKU GRACCIOZA-PRESTIGE-MAT-new - 1 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'attribute_id' cannot be null -

I am pretty certain it's the type column because I changed it to "_type" and it would go through but the product imported is not set as a configurable product type, which is the whole point. I am trying to set color and size attributes to the configurable product.

Here is a shorter snippet of my csv:

```
attribute_set, type, sku, configurable_attributes, color, size, name
Color_Size, simple, GRACCIOZA-PRESTIGE-MAT-80X120-ST, "color,size", Stone, 80cmx120, Graccioza Prestige Bath mat

Color_Size, configurable, GRACCIOZA-PRESTIGE-MAT-new, "color,size", Graccioza Prestige Bath mat
```

The first row is the column names, second is the simple product that I am defining and the third row is the configurable product that I am trying to make it work. The simple products are imported perfectly. I've got the configurable plugin installed for magmi already.

Please help guys. I have over 700 products that I need uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From memory, I think your syntax may be wrong. I don't believe you need the " quote mark's around color,size.

Also I think 1048 refers to the row number in your csv file, not sure if this takes into account the first row of column names in your csv but look around row 1047,1048 & 1049 for any syntax errors.

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually, although the essence of the answer is correct, 1048 in this case refers to the MySQL error code for the "column can not be null" error: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_bad_null_error